# Can you check if a PSN code is valid without redeeming it?

Tags: psn

I have a code for additional content on a Playstation game, and I want to know whether it is still valid, but I don't want to redeem it for myself.

If I enter it in the Playstation Store (on PS3, PS4 or the website), does it get redeemed to my account automatically, or can I enter it without redeeming? If it gets redeemed automatically, is there another way to check if it is valid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to check code is by trying to redeem it. After entering the code, if the code is valid, there will be a confirmation step, and you can cancel the operation. If the code is invalid or expired it will be rejected immediately with an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the code, but do not hit 'submit'.

If it is valid, it will have a checkmark confirming that it is valid.

Comment: Why so many downvotes, I believe this is right. When I entered my PS Plus code it showed a checkmark before I redeemed it. If this is wrong, could you leave a comment on why instead of just plain downvoting?

Comment: This is explaining a valid solution. Albeit not entirely the way most of us would want, but thats not this user's fault. Welcome to Arqade Ethan, please continue doing work!